# How to show only half of the next slide in slick.js slider

Tags: carousel, slick.js

In slick slider, there is an option called "centerMode" which basically certer elements and show some portion of prev/next item depending on 'centerPadding'. Another option is "slidesToShow: 2.3" that basically shows 2 item and half of the prev/next item but I want to show two full item and only half of the next item like this :

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add this to your CSS:

```
.slick-list{padding:0 20% 0 0;}
```

Note: It won't work if you'll add it in the browser inspector. You have to add it before you load the page.